# match few charcaters in a word

Tags: java

I have sentences like:

```
Slno:0 ahdhajdhjahdjahjdhahd <>
Slno:1 ahdhajdhjahdjahjdhahd <>
Slno:2 ahdhajdhjahdjahjdhahd <>
```

I want to compare with the first 5 charters as "Slno:x" where x is a integer.
if that condition is met I want to print the rest of the lines. and the remove the last <>
so the output looks like:

```
       ahdhajdhjahdjahjdhahd
       ahdhajdhjahdjahjdhahd
       ahdhajdhjahdjahjdhahd
```

I tried doing:

if string1.charAt(1)=='S' for all charcaters and than printed from string1[5] to end.
 if that conditions are true. Looking for a more better logic

Comment: You wanted to check for "SLno:x" I thought.. not just first character..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your requirement correctly i think this would work.try this:

```
 public static void main(string..args) {
String s1= "Slno:0 ahdhajdhjahdjahjdhahd <>";

    String[] sSplit = s1.split("\\s");
    String f[]= sSplit[0].split(":");
   ;
    if(f[0].equals("Slno") && checkInt(f[1])) {
        System.out.println(sSplit[1]);
    }



}
public static boolean checkInt(String i) {
    try {
    Integer.parseInt(i);
    return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response chaitanya as mentioned I can have strings as: "Slno:0 ahd ha jdhjahd jahjdha hd <>";

Comment: @TheLearner would you have multiple strings of same format as in my code ??

Comment: need not be I have multiple lines with spaces in sentances. example: String s1= "Slno:0 ahdh ajdh jahdjahj dhahd <>";

Comment: @TheLearner just to be more precise. do you just wanna check if s1 has "Slno:0" as first 5 characters and if so you wanna print your desired output ?

Comment: I want to check if the first 4 characters is sln0, than the following is a integer. than print the entire line removing the slno, integer and the last <>

Comment: @chaitanya10.. That code may not print the complete sentence.. As OP says that he can have `spaces` in between his sentence..

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex and substring.. if you spaces between your sentences: -

```
String s1 = "Slno:0 ahdhajdhjahdjahjdhahd <>";

if (s1.substring(0, 6).matches("Slno:\\d")) {
     System.out.println(s1.substring(7, s1.length() - 3));
}
```

Output: -

```
ahdhajdhjahdjahjdhahd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

**Example:** "Slno:0 ahdhajdhjahdjahjdhahd <>"

Split the Sentence to three parts using `split` method setting delimiters as space.

```
StringOne = "Slno:0"
StringTwo = "ahdhajdhjahdjahjdhahd"
StringThree = "<>"
```

Use contains method to match the input. If the given input matches the first part of the string then print the second part of the string.

Comment: that 0 can be any integer. so I cannot predict. all I know is it is a integer. StringTwo can be sentences with lines.